# How To Define An Outer Product (in xAct)?

Tags: matrix, tensors, products, xact

I am working with xAct / xCoba / xTras and I would like to construct a matrix out of a vector.
So, I have a vector `V` on a manifold `M`:

```
DefManifold[M, 3, IndexRange[a, n]]
DefTensor[V[\[Mu]], M]
```

Now, I would like to take the outer / dyadic product to construct a 4x4 matrix on the manifold M4 by doing something like

```
{1,B[mu]} * {1,B[nu]}
= 
{{1 , B1    , B2    , B3},
{B1 , B1.B1 , B1.B2 , B1.B3},
{B2 , B2.B1 , B2.B2 , B2.B3},
{B3 , B3.B1 , B3.B2 , B3.B3}}
```

where `*` is the outer product and `.` the scalar (or dot) product between the vector components `Bi`.

How can this be done? Thank you very much in advance for your reply. :)

Comment: Would [Outer (dyadic) product between vectors of the same index in two lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199211/27951) help?

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB for your reply. Actually, Outer[Times, {1, Bi[\[Mu]]}, {1, Bi[\[Nu]]}]//MatrixForm looks good, but when I try Outer[Times, {1, Bi[\[Mu]]}, {1, Bi[\[Nu]]}] - {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} it tells me "IndexForm::nouse: Attempting to apply IndexForm on {<<2>>}." and "Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in [...]". It seems that it doesn't know how long Bi[\[Mu]] is. :S